# Jenkins not running TestNG Tests

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng

I've got an TestNG project which was running on Jenkins. For some reason which I don't know it stopped running the tests. It compiles perfectly but it doesn't run the the test. Here is the output of a run:

```
  <===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
  log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger 
  (org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BooleanConverter).
  log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
  Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Java\jenkins-1.523\workspace\TEST_HEAD_NOEXPORT\CMS-WEB   SELENIUM-WEB-TEST\pom.xml clean install
  [INFO] Scanning for projects...
  [INFO]                                                                         
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Building TEST-CMS-WEB 0.0.1
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ Web ---
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ Web ---
  [debug] execute contextualize
  [INFO] Using 'cp1252' encoding to copy filtered resources.
  [INFO] Copying 69 resources
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ Web ---
  [INFO] Compiling 73 source files to C:\Java\jenkins-1.523\workspace\TEST_HEAD_NOEXPORT\CMS-WEB\SELENIUM-WEB-TEST\target\classes
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ Web ---
  [debug] execute contextualize
  [INFO] Using 'cp1252' encoding to copy filtered resources.
  [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Java\jenkins-1.523\workspace\TEST_HEAD_NOEXPORT\CMS-WEB\SELENIUM-WEB-TEST\src\test\resources
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Web ---
  [INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Java\jenkins-1.523\workspace\TEST_HEAD_NOEXPORT\CMS-WEB\SELENIUM-WEB-TEST\target\test-classes
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Web ---
  [JENKINS] Recording test results
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ Web ---
  [INFO] Building jar: C:\Java\jenkins-1.523\workspace\TEST_HEAD_NOEXPORT\CMS-WEB\SELENIUM-WEB-TEST\target\Web-0.0.1.jar
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ Web ---
  [INFO] Installing C:\Java\jenkins-1.523\workspace\TEST_HEAD_NOEXPORT\CMS-WEB\SELENIUM-WEB-TEST\target\Web-0.0.1.jar to C:\.m2\repository\Test\Web\0.0.1\Web-0.0.1.jar
  [INFO] Installing C:\Java\jenkins-1.523\workspace\TEST_HEAD_NOEXPORT\CMS-WEB\SELENIUM-WEB-TEST\pom.xml to C:\.m2\repository\Test\Web\0.0.1\Web-0.0.1.pom
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Total time: 5.211s
  [INFO] Finished at: Wed Jan 15 14:21:03 UYST 2014
  [INFO] Final Memory: 26M/310M
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [JENKINS] Archiving C:\Java\jenkins-1.523\workspace\TEST_HEAD_NOEXPORT\CMS-WEB\SELENIUM-WEB-TEST\pom.xml to C:\Java\jenkins-1.523\jobs\TEST_HEAD_NOEXPORT\modules\Test$Web\builds\2014-01-15_14-20-56\archive\Test\Web\0.0.1\Web-0.0.1.pom
  [JENKINS] Archiving C:\Java\jenkins-1.523\workspace\TEST_HEAD_NOEXPORT\CMS-WEB\SELENIUM-WEB-TEST\target\Web-0.0.1.jar to C:\Java\jenkins-1.523\jobs\TEST_HEAD_NOEXPORT\modules\Test$Web\builds\2014-01-15_14-20-56\archive\Test\Web\0.0.1\Web-0.0.1.jar
  Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
```

If anyone knows what could be happening I would appreciate the help.

Comment: i'm seeing nowhere where it's finding your tests.  Since you are using maven, are your tests under `src/test/java` ?

Comment: they are under src/main/java, but the thing is im using TestNG with maven surefire and im:

<suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/testsCasesRun/smokeTestPlan.xml

</suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>

Comment: per maven convention, your tests will not be run if they aren't in `src/test/java`.  Either move them there, or you need to find out how to explicitly tell maven that your test directory is in `src/main/java`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using Maven Surefire,  did you correctly specify a "test include" filter?  The test phase will search the packages in src/test/java  for classes containing the @Test annotation.  It's easy to misconfigure Maven for the location of the src/test/java directory and so just be careful and you will figure it out.

Comment: yes im using Maven Surefire and i have specified it in the pom, this way: <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    <configuration>
     <includes>
      <include>**/Test*.java</include>
     </includes>
     <suiteXmlFiles>
      <suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/testsCasesRun/jenkins.xml</suiteXmlFile>
     </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

Comment: That's not the part I was saying to be careful about.  Be very careful about how you configured (or accepted defaults) and placed your src/main and src/test dir locations.

Answer (score 0):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
```

Include maven surefire plugin end of the properties & before the dependencies. Use your "TestNG" XML file name.Use above code.